# How to get the values of div using its id after retrieving the values from database using php

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am trying to get the values of div elements using Simple HTML Dom Parser. Its working fine for only hard coded values. Here is the hard coded stuff.

```
<table>
<tr><td class='none'><div class='drag' id='d1'>1</div></td></tr>
<tr><td class='none'><div class='drag' id='d2'>2</div></td></tr>
<tr><td class='none'><div class='drag' id='d3'>3</div></td></tr>
```

Apart from these constant values i need to get the other id values which are displayed based on the selection from the drop-down menu.

```
<form method="post" name="order" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select id='test' name='test'>
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='test1'>Test1</option>
<option value='test2'>Test2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

After the selection they click the continue button which redirects them to the same page and here is my script that displays id's from database.

```
<?php
$i=4;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{ 
$query = mysql_query("select * from test_demo where test_requested='$_POST[test]'");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<tr><td class='none'><div class='drag' id='d$i'>". $result['oid'] ."</div></td></tr>";
$i++;
}
}
echo "</table>"
?>
```

Now i want to get the order id's 1,2,3 and remaining id's retrieved from the database. In order to get these values i am using a Values button on click goes to retrieve.php file.

In retrieve.php file i am using Simple html dom parser to get the values. Here is the code.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
//test.php contains my hard coded html and php code 
$html = file_get_html('test.php');
$temp = '1';
                    //usig div name we are retrieving the values
            foreach($html->find('div#d5') as $e)
        $result[]= $e->innertext;
        print_r($result); 

?>
```

In the place of d5 if i could mention d1 or d2 or d3. I could able to get the values 1,2,3 respectively. But i am unable to get the order id values which are retrieved from the database. The div ids for these elements starts from d4 and so on. Where could be I am going wrong?

Comment: `file_get_html` uses the GET method, but your script only performs the database query when the POST method is used.

Comment: @Barmar I just now tried with GET method but still it does not work.

Comment: Did you add `&test=test1` to the URL, and change `test.php` to use `$_GET['test']`?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't get your changes. could you elaborate more on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

First, PHP scripts aren't run if you access them as ordinary files. You need to change the URL to go through the server:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/path/to/test.php');
```

Second, you need to provide the value of the `test` parameter in the URL, so it should be:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/path/to/test.php?test=test1');
```

Third, in `test.php` you need to access the parameter using `$_GET`, not `$_POST`, when it's accessed this way:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    $test = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['test']);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from test_demo where test_requested='$test'");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, you have to use double quotes.

Comment: Still its not working. I have made all the changes as mentioned in your post.

Comment: You're still missing `http://` from the beginning of your URL. So it's treating it as a local filename, not going through the server.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting turned on, so you see these errors.

Comment: When putting code in comments, wrap it in backticks so it won't be molested.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. If you just call `file_get_contents`, what does the result look like? Are there any errors in it?

Comment: I enabled error reporting its not pointing me any errors. Its showing me the hard-coded stuff but not the ones from the database.

Comment: yeah its throwing me an error. Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: That means that `file_get_html()` is failing for some reason.

Comment: yeah i tried to print out the entire document. I could able to see only the hard-coded stuff is being taken into consideration. I am not sure what changes are need.

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning something?

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar. Finally figured it out. I am clicking continue button after selecting the test type from drop down menu. After the test type if we could give those additional details. I am able to get it.